# Handling different configurations with git

Tags: git, development-environment, production-environment

I am doing a Laravel 4 project, and there is an option on mail.pjp, where you can pretend to send an email, but you actually are logging it locally into a file. This is useful for development.

The problem I have is with version control. If I check in, this option as "true", then I risk that when I update the production server, it might disable emails if I am not careful.

On the other hand, if I check in the file in git as "true", it might happen what happened today, that I lost a good couple of hours trying to understand why the mail was not working because I forgot I had to change this option for my development environment.

What way could I handle these "production vs development" configuration issues with git?

Comment: 2 questions: does your configuration file change over time? What's your deployment process?

Comment: Well, if my configuration file will change on the future, is something that I can not foresee at this point. My deployment process is quite basic. I just it `git pull origin master` on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Git: application configuration and different environments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3214016/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git to manage one codebase but have different environments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2964120/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I track system-specific config files in a repo/project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2154948/456814).

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How do I open source my Rails' apps without giving away the app's secret keys and credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3207575/456814).

Comment: One way Ruby on Rails applications deal with this is to store environment specific configurations in an unversioned file for each environment, and load them into environment varibles using [Foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Have a branch for each configuration.

For instance, you could have a `production` branch and a `dev` branch.

On the `production` branch, just make one commit to change the configuration file, then use the `dev` branch the same way you used your `master` branch.

The deployment process becomes

On dev:

- git checkout production
- git merge dev
- git push origin production

On production:

- git pull origin production

### Or split your configuration file

And maybe add some runtime test to pick the good one at the right time.

Comment: Just to be sure, those 3 commands that you write, should I type them on the dev machine, or in the production server?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and use the following solution which might be a bit heavy but works well to separate 'private' data from a public project.

The idea is to not put your configuration file under your normal git repository but in an a private one.
Ideally you would like the private repo to be a submodule of the public one, but you have to do it the other way (to hide the private repo from the public one).

For this, I create a `private` repo which contains my configuration file. then I create a submodule containing the `public` one and add a link to the configuration file.

The directory structure looks like :

```
private + (private git repo)
        |
        +- config.conf
        |
        +- public + (public git repo)
                  |
                  + config -> ../config.conf
                  |
                  + src
```

Then I have a `devel` and a `production` branch on the private repo with the two version
of the configuration file. But I never really touch those directory.

When a new developper arrives he just forks the devel branch and the works inside the public as if there is no umbrella project. Just pull push as normal.

When you need to deploy just go on the production machine and update the `public` submodule.
If you need to update the production configuration file, just update it on the production machine and push it. Alternatively you can switch locally to the `production` branch, make the necessary changes and push them to the production server.

Hope it's clear.